# How to model recursive ASN.1 specs using PyASN1?

Tags: python, asn.1

In [PKCS#15](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2141) there is a structure in `CommonObjectAttributes` that describes the rules for access to an object. To my great chagrin it's recursive, i.e, it can contain itself:

```
SecurityCondition ::= CHOICE {
    authId Identifier,
    not [0] SecurityCondition,
    and [1] SEQUENCE SIZE (2..pkcs15-ub-securityConditions) OF SecurityCondition,
    or  [2] SEQUENCE SIZE (2..pkcs15-ub-securityConditions) OF SecurityCondition,
    ... -- For future extensions
}
```

I'm stumped on how to model this with pyasn1. I guess I can impose a fixed level of recursions and simply let them depend on each other, but that's not a very attractive solution in my opinion. Does anyone have a better idea?

### Update

Testing Ilya Etingofs approach by leaving out the definition of `SecurityCondition` at first I got this:

```
 class SecurityCondition(univ.Choice):
    pass

securityConditionComponentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('authId', univ.OctetString().subtype(
            subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(0, univ.Integer(255)))
        ),
        namedtype.NamedType('not', SecurityCondition().subtype(
            implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 0)
            )
        ),
        namedtype.NamedType('and', univ.SequenceOf(componentType=SecurityCondition).subtype(
            #implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 1),
            #subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(2, univ.Integer(255))
            )
        ),
        namedtype.NamedType('or', univ.SequenceOf(componentType=SecurityCondition).subtype(
            #implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 2),
            #subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(2, univ.Integer(255))
            )
        )
    )
SecurityCondition.componentType = securityConditionComponentType
```

With example usage:

```
# Example usage
inner = univ.SequenceOf()
inner.setComponentByPosition(0, SecurityCondition().setComponentByName("authId", "\x02"))
inner.setComponentByPosition(1, SecurityCondition().setComponentByName("authId", "\x03"))

outer = univ.SequenceOf()
outer.setComponentByPosition(0, SecurityCondition().setComponentByName("authId", "\x01"))
outer.setComponentByPosition(1, SecurityCondition().setComponentByName("or", inner))

wrapper = SecurityCondition().setComponentByName("and", outer)
```

And it seems to work if no subtype spec or implicit tags are used:

```
>>> print wrapper.prettyPrint()
SecurityCondition:
 and=SequenceOf:
  SecurityCondition:
   authId=0x01
  SecurityCondition:
   or=SequenceOf:
    SecurityCondition:
     authId=0x02
    SecurityCondition:
     authId=0x03

SEQUENCE(2 elem)
    OCTET STRING(2 byte) 01
    SEQUENCE(2 elem)
        OCTET STRING(1 byte) 02
        OCTET STRING(1 byte) 03
```

If `implicitTag` and `subtypeSpec` are uncommented the error

```
PyAsn1Error: Component type error SequenceOf() vs
SequenceOf().setComponentByPosition(0, SecurityCondition().setComponentByPosition(0,
     OctetString(hexValue='02'))).setComponentByPosition(1,
     SecurityCondition().setComponentByPosition(0, OctetString(hexValue='03')))
```

occurs. Which coincidentally is the same error I get if trying the fixed number of recursions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my previous hack did not really work. Updated to a more aggressive hack:

```
class SecurityCondition(univ.Choice):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('authId', univ.OctetString().subtype(subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255))),
        namedtype.NamedType('not', univ.Any()),  # just a placeholder
        namedtype.NamedType('and', univ.Any()),  # just a placeholder
        namedtype.NamedType('or', univ.Any())    # just a placeholder
    )

SecurityCondition.componentType[1]._NamedType__type = SecurityCondition().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 0))
SecurityCondition.componentType[2]._NamedType__type =  univ.SequenceOf(componentType=SecurityCondition()).subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClass.ontext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 1), subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(2, 255))
SecurityCondition.componentType[3]._NamedType__type =  univ.SequenceOf(componentType=SecurityCondition()).subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 2), subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(2, 255))

# Initialize an instance of SecurityCondition

top = SecurityCondition() # SecurityCondition
top['and'] = None         # SecurityCondition->SequenceOf
top['and'][0] = None      # SecurityCondition->SequenceOf->SecurityCondition
top['and'][0]['authId'] = "\x02"
top['and'][1] = None      # SecurityCondition->SequenceOf->SecurityCondition
top['and'][1]['authId'] = "\x03"

print(top.prettyPrint())
```

Right, that's ugly and creates cyclic references. On the bright side it seems to work.

Comment: The problem is that the SecurityCondition is instantiated in the componentType specification when it's not yet a completed class. So while I applaud your idea, I cant see it working :)

Comment: I tested anyways, and it worked up to the point when `subtypeSpec` and `implicitTag` was used. Do you see any errors with the code in the example?

Comment: Cool! It's not pretty, but it seems to work, both for encoding and decoding!